# How to properly access session cookie in route

Tags: node.js, express, session-cookies

I'm attempting to store a value in my express app using cookie-session. I would like to access this value in any of my routes.
I can do this perfectly fine in my index.js file.

```
var app = express();
app.set("trust proxy", 1);
app.use(
  cookieSession({
    name: "session",
    secret: "key",
    httpOnly: true,
    maxAge: 30 * 60 * 1000,
    secure: false,
    overwrite: false
  })
);


app.get("/", function(req, res, next) {
  // Update views
  req.session.views = (req.session.views || 0) + 1;
  req.session.key = "some key I set"
  // print out 3 views key = some key I set
  res.end(req.session.views + " views " + "key = " + req.session.key);
});
```

The problem I have is when I try to set or get anything on my session in one of my routes I get an error stating

> Cannot set property 'key' of undefined

This is my testRoute file

```
module.exports = app => {
  app.get("/test",(req, res) => {
    // throws error
    res.end(req.session.key);
  });
};
```

Ant this is how I let my index.js file know about it.

```
var app = express();
// Tell Index about my route
require("./routes/authRoutes")(app);

app.set("trust proxy", 1);
app.use(
  cookieSession({
    name: "session",
    secret: "key",
    httpOnly: true,
    maxAge: 30 * 60 * 1000,
    secure: false,
    overwrite: false
  })
);
```

I'm very new to express and the concepts surrounding middlewares and routes.

What's the correct way to give access to the cookie session in all of my routes.

Comment: where in your code do you put `require("./routes/testRoute")(app);` (which line number)

Comment: where have you added app.use(router)?

Comment: @Alex I updated my question.

Comment: yep, thought that'd be the case. See my answer

Comment: @SushobhNadiger none of the examples i've been learning from use app.use(router)

Comment: @dubbeat what version of express are you using?

Comment: Im using express 4.16.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect the problem is you're `require` ing your route before you set the session up:

```
var app = express();
require("./routes/testRoute")(app);
app.set("trust proxy", 1);

//you haven't told your app about the session
require("./routes/testRoute")(app);

///until now....
app.use(
  cookieSession({
    name: "session",
    secret: "key",
    httpOnly: true,
    maxAge: 30 * 60 * 1000,
    secure: false,
    overwrite: false
  })
);
```

Try this

```
var app = express();
require("./routes/testRoute")(app);
app.set("trust proxy", 1);

app.use(
  cookieSession({
    name: "session",
    secret: "key",
    httpOnly: true,
    maxAge: 30 * 60 * 1000,
    secure: false,
    overwrite: false
  })
);

//require route after session has been set up
require("./routes/testRoute")(app);
```

As an a-side, `Router` may be better to use, that `require`'ing your routes.
Full details here: https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#router

Comment: Ok, what you suggested makes perfect sense. Unfortunately after  making the edit I'm left with the same error.

Comment: Apologies I commented too soon. This is the right answer. Also thanks for the link

Comment: No problem, glad it helped